# Fastest way to draw many primitives in Allegro 5

Tags: performance, graphics, bitmap, drawing, allegro5

I want to draw a very large amount of triangles (up to 600000).
What I did first was to:

```
al_init();
display = al_create_display();
```

and then loop through my triangles and

```
al_draw_triangle(); each one.
```

Finally I did

```
al_flip_display();
```

This was not very fast though. I read that it helps to draw to a bitmap on hold first and then draw that bitmap to the display.
I tried to do this in the following fashion (sketched):

```
al_init();
display = al_create_display();
bitmap = al_create_bitmap();
al_set_target_bitmap(bitmap);
al_hold_bitmap_drawing(1);
for every triangle: 
    al_draw_triangle();
al_hold_bitmap_drawing(0);
al_set_target_bitmap(al_get_backbuffer(display));
al_draw_bitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, 0);
al_flip_display();
```

This is just as fast as the previous method though.
How can I correctly buffer my triangles to reduce the amount of draws?
What is the most efficient way to draw many primitives in Allegro 5?

Thanks for all answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`al_hold_bitmap_drawing` does nothing for primitives. [This thread](https://www.allegro.cc/forums/thread/611825) has some discussion on the topic, including a [suggestion](https://www.allegro.cc/forums/thread/611825/974692#target) to buffer all of your primitives and make one call to `al_draw_prim`:

> The difference is that I only call al_draw_prim once, after buffering possibly hundreds of primitives. The primitive drawing functions will kick off a batch every time.

Comment: Thanks, I will try using a vertex buffer